# Programming Breakout in Racket (BSL) using big-bang. Running into an error upon placing the paddle

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, breakout, racket-student-languages

The goal is to make the game Breakout and doing it by steps. I'm already having problems with the first step which is implementing a paddle. The ball and bouncing of the ball was already predefined and given. I wish to put it in the (define (render ball) like so:

```
(define (render ball worldstate)
(place-image BALL-IMG
           (posn-x (ball-loc ball))
           (posn-y (ball-loc ball))
(place-image PADDLE (posn-x (world-state-paddle worldstate)) (posn-y (world-state-paddle worldstate))
           SCENE)))
```

However I'm getting the error "to-draw: expected function of one argument as first argument; given function of 2 arguments " I'm not sure how I can make the code better. Here's what my code looks like so far. The ball is already predefined as well as the tick. So far I cannot even place the paddle in but the ball bounces around (no bricks yet implemented)

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define WIDTH 200)
(define HEIGHT 200)
(define BALL-RADIUS 10)
(define BALL-IMG (circle BALL-RADIUS "solid" "red"))
(define SCENE (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT))

(define PADDLE (rectangle 60 10 "solid" "green"))
(define SPEED 4)

(define-struct vel (delta-x delta-y))
; a Vel is a structure: (make-vel Number Number)
; interp. the velocity vector of a moving object

(define-struct ball (loc velocity))
; a Ball is a structure: (make-ball Posn Vel)
; interp. the position and velocity of a object 

; Posn Vel -> Posn
; applies q to p and simulates the movement in one clock tick
(check-expect (posn+vel (make-posn 5 6) (make-vel 1 2))
              (make-posn 6 8))

(define (posn+vel p q)
  (make-posn (+ (posn-x p) (vel-delta-x q))
             (+ (posn-y p) (vel-delta-y q))))


; Ball -> Ball
; computes movement of ball in one clock tick
(check-expect (move-ball (make-ball (make-posn 20 30)
                                    (make-vel 5 10)))
              (make-ball (make-posn 25 40)
                     (make-vel 5 10)))

(define (move-ball ball)
  (make-ball (posn+vel (ball-loc ball)
                       (ball-velocity ball))
         (ball-velocity ball)))


; A Collision is either
; - "top"
; - "down"
; - "left"
; - "right"
; - "none"
; interp. the location where a ball collides with a wall

; Posn -> Collision
; detects with which of the walls (if any) the ball collides
(check-expect (collision (make-posn 0 12))  "left")
(check-expect (collision (make-posn 15 HEIGHT)) "down")
(check-expect (collision (make-posn WIDTH 12))  "right")
(check-expect (collision (make-posn 15 0)) "top")
(check-expect (collision (make-posn 55 55)) "none")

(define (collision posn)
  (cond
    [(<= (posn-x posn) BALL-RADIUS) "left"]
    [(<= (posn-y posn) BALL-RADIUS)  "top"]
    [(>= (posn-x posn) (- WIDTH BALL-RADIUS)) "right"]
    [(>= (posn-y posn) (- HEIGHT BALL-RADIUS)) "down"]
    [else "none"]))

; Vel Collision -> Vel  
; computes the velocity of an object after a collision
(check-expect (bounce (make-vel 3 4) "left")
              (make-vel -3 4))
(check-expect (bounce (make-vel 3 4) "top")
              (make-vel 3 -4))
(check-expect (bounce (make-vel 3 4) "none")
              (make-vel 3 4))

(define (bounce vel collision)
  (cond [(or (string=? collision "left")
         (string=? collision "right"))
     (make-vel (- (vel-delta-x vel))
               (vel-delta-y vel))]
    [(or (string=? collision "down")
         (string=? collision "top"))
     (make-vel (vel-delta-x vel)
               (- (vel-delta-y vel)))]
    [else vel]))

; WorldState is a Ball
; interp. the current state of the ball

; WorldState -> Image
; renders ball at its position
;(check-expect (image? (render INITIAL-BALL)) #true)

(define (render ball worldstate)
  (place-image BALL-IMG
           (posn-x (ball-loc ball))
           (posn-y (ball-loc ball))
           SCENE))

; WorldState -> WorldState
; moves ball to its next location
(check-expect (tick (make-ball (make-posn 20 12) (make-vel 1 2)))
              (make-ball (make-posn 21 14) (make-vel 1 2)))

(define (tick ball)
  (move-ball (make-ball (ball-loc ball)
                    (bounce (ball-velocity ball)
                            (collision (ball-loc ball))))))


(define-struct world-state (paddle speed ball))

;WorldState is a structure (make-world-state paddle speed Ball)

(define Example-world-state (make-world-state PADDLE SPEED (make-ball (make-posn 20 12)
                                                      (make-vel 1 2))))

;mouse
;Worldstate Number Number MouseEvent -> Worldstate
;moves the paddle
(define (mouse worldstate x y mouseEvent)
  (make-world-state (world-state-speed worldstate) (world-state-ball     worldstate)
                (cond
                  [(string=? mouseEvent "move")
                   (make-posn x y)]
                  [else (world-state-paddle worldstate)])))




(define INITIAL-BALL (make-ball (make-posn 20 12)
                            (make-vel 1 2)))

(define INITIAL-WORLD-STATE INITIAL-BALL)

(define (main state)
  (big-bang state (on-tick tick 0.01) (to-draw render) (on-mouse mouse)))

(main INITIAL-WORLD-STATE)
```

I appreciate any tips given!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your 'render' function signature is

> WorldState -> Image

but, render gets 2 parameters:

```
 `(define (render ball worldstate) ...)`
```

Signatures are used to type check and better document your work for others to understand, in this case it helped me quickly find the problem :)

According to the error you supplied:

`(to-draw render)`

in function 'main' is expecting render to be a funtion that receives only **1 parameter** while in your code it is defined as a function that takes **2 params**:

Check out render and to-draw here:
[to-draw@docs.racket-lang.org](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html#%28form._world._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Funiverse..rkt%29._to-draw%29%29)

Comment: I see, so when doing (to-draw ...) or (on-tick ...) only one parameter is accepted? or would it accept 2 parameters if I give it two parameters like (to-draw render render2)?

Comment: These functions are both overloaded, to-draw can take 1 or 3 parameters. From the documentation in my answer:
(to-draw render-expr) = "...call the function render-expr...Its size is determined by the size of the first generated image."
or you can use:
(to-draw render-expr width-expr height-expr) = "...use a width-expr by height-expr canvas instead of one determined by the first generated image." 
Check out [on-tick](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html#%28form._world._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Funiverse..rkt%29._on-tick%29%29) too.

Answer (score 0):

The `render` function only takes the world state as a parameter, and you can't add more parameter.
You already have the paddle in the state, and you can retrieve the ball and the paddle from it:

```
(define (render world)
    (place-image BALL-IMG
           (posn-x (ball-loc (world-state-ball world))
           (posn-y (ball-loc (world-state-ball world))
    ...
```

You might want to write separate rendering functions for the components:

```
(define (render-ball ball)
     ...)

(define (render-paddle paddle)
     ...)

(define (render-world world)
    (render-ball (world-state-ball world))
    (render-paddle (world-state-paddle world))
```

Comment: So if I have these different renders and then in the end put the render-world in this case into my (define (main state) everything should show up? :D Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @DelightWang Well, they *should*, but I'm not promising anything ;-) (Making separate functions will come in handy when you want to add a multi-ball mode, or a two-player mode.)